# C accessing structures in different files with pointers - dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, structure

I can't find a solution with the following C code

I have 3 files as follows:

1) story1.c

where

```
struct Example1 
{
int first_element;           
int second_element;
...
};

int function1(Example1 *m, ...) 
{
...
m->first_element = m->second_element;
m->second_element = /* changing int data */;

return /* other integer */;
}
```

2) story1.h

where

```
typedef struct Example1 Example1;
```

3) story2.c

where

```
typedef struct Example2 {
Example1 *ptr;
int res2;
...
} Example2;

[...]

static void mother_function(Example2 *s)
{
int res;

res = function1(s->ptr, ...);
}

static void last_function(Example2 *s)
{
if ( ( &(s->ptr)->first_element == 10 ) &&
             ( (((*s).ptr).second_element) == 44 ) &&
             /* other conditions */ )
            s->res2 = /* new value */;
}
```

mother_function calls function1 which sets m->first_element and m->second_element, e.g. 10 and 44

now I would like last_function to access these new born [in function1 of another file] values starting from pointer s to evaluate the if [conceptually speaking I would like to do something like:

```
if( (s->ptr->first_element==10) && (s->ptr->second_element==44) ) then...
```

I tried to write in 3 ways to get it done:
1) `s->ptr->first_element`
2) `( &(s->ptr)->first_element == 10 )`
3) `( (((*s).ptr).second_element) == 44 )`

and compiler gave me the following errors:

1) `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`
2) `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`
3) `error: request for member ‘second_element’ in something not a structure or union`

What is the reason of these messages and how can I practically fix this issue?

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `struct Example1 { ... };` lines from `story1.c` to `story1.h` (and make sure `story2.c` includes `story1.h`) so that `story2.c` will have access to the definition of `struct Example1`.  Then writing `s->ptr->first_element` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some explanation to Jwodder's solution: `s->ptr->first_element` is trying to access the member of `struct Example1`, however,   `struct Example1` is defined in story1.c so it's invisible to story2.c.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope

Comment: I'm answering only now because I had these files on my office PC... it works perfectly! thanks to @jwodder for the solution and bl4ck5un for the explanation!